# Kerberized Hadoop Hive Beeline access issue

Tags: hadoop, hive, kerberos, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to get hiveserver2 via beeline to work with a kerberized HDP 2.3 cluster. I am on amazon ec2.

Once I get a renewable ticket i am able to perform hdfs operations and also launch mr jobs..

Even though hive cli is not via hive server 2..  thats working as well..

When I try to connect via beeline..  I get an error around no tgt found..  when i actually have it befor lauching the beeline command

I am getting the ticket as my own user..   but I am using hive/@ for the principal..

Just for testing i tried using hives own keytab to get the ticket as well..  did not work..

Lots of articles only suggested to renew token before launching beeline..  did not work

One article suggested to use a different principal and keytab for the hive metastore…   did not work

Sasl is enabled as suggested

Here is the /etc/krb5. conf:

```
[logging]

default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log

kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log

admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log



[libdefaults]

default_realm = ABC.COM

dns_lookup_realm = false

dns_lookup_kdc = false

ticket_lifetime = 30m

renew_lifetime = 10h

forwardable = true

udp_preference_limit = 1



[realms]

ABC.COM = {

kdc = localhost

admin_server = localhost

default_principal_flags = +renewable

max_renewable_life = 7d 0h 0m 0s

}



[domain_realm]

.abc.com = ABC.COM

abc.com = ABC.COM
```

TicketDetails:

```
$ klist -f
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_500
Default principal: ec2-user@ABC.COM

Valid starting Expires Service principal
10/17/15 13:40:26 10/17/15 14:10:26 krbtgt/ABC.COM@ABC.COM
renew until 10/17/15 23:04:27, Flags: FRIT

$ date
Sat Oct 17 13:41:02 EDT 2015
```

The beeline connect string is:

```
!connect jdbc:hive2://<hive_host>:10000/default;principal=hive/ip-<hive_host>.ec2.internal@ABC.COM
```

netstat output for hive server 2:

```
$ sudo netstat -tunlp | grep 10000
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:10000 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 11272/java
```

I had tried binding it to the private ip as well.. same result..

Whole strack trace from Beeline

```
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://<hive_host>:10000/default;principal=hive/ip-<hive_host>.ec2.internal@ABC.COM: GSS initiate failed (state=08S01,code=0)
0: jdbc:hive2://<hive_host>:10000/default (closed)> 15/10/17 13:06:14 [main]: ERROR transport.TSaslTransport: SASL negotiation failure
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:212)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.handleSaslStartMessage(TSaslClientTransport.java:94)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:271)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:52)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport.open(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:210)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:180)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:142)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:207)
```

Any suggestions on what I am missing ?

The KMS is Ranger KMS

Answer (score 0):

OK the solution is, on your systems do mkdir the following /etc/hadoop/conf/
and add this under it core-site.xml  with just this settings

```
<configuration>  <property>
      <name>hadoop.security.authentication</name>
      <value>kerberos</value>
    </property> </configuration>
```

This looks like a Beeline issue? even though we can specify auth=kerberos on the command line, its still needs this (at least worked for me)!  I use Ubuntu os.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and I have fixed it by setting the `HIVE_CONF_DIR` variable to point to the hive-conf.

The node, I was trying this on was not part of Hadoop cluster, but a temporary node and it did not have configuration in `/etc`.
http://blog.godatadriven.com/beeline-client-secured-cluster.html also had information that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

"GSS initiate failed" exception will occur if the kerberos authentication fails. Please make sure you already have renew the authentication before try to establish connection.

Use klist command to check the expiry date and time. If auth. expired, use kinit command to renew auth.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was able to connect the HS2 from one server and not able to connect from another server.

As I found the issue with the beeline version.

Problematic server beeline version :

````
>beeline --version
Beeline version 2.3.9 by Apache Hive```
````

Able to connect the HS2 server Beeline version :

```
>beeline --version
Beeline version 3.1.3000.7.1.7.0-551 by Apache Hive
```

I changed the beeline utility path and was able to connect the HS2

```
[airflow@hostname bin]$ which beeline
/usr/local/bin/beeline
[airflow@hostname bin]$ cd /bin
[airflow@hostname bin]$ ./beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://$HOSTNAME:10000/default;principal=hive/$HOSTNAME@DEV.DCOE;
```